# centos 6.6, sh: zip: command not found

Tags: centos6, php5, php.ini

Centos 6.6 64bit on OpenVZ VPS.

I tried a phpinfo.php file using only the following code:

```
<?php
var_dump( exec('zip -r domains.zip "domains"') );
// phpinfo();
?>
```

.

```
The php error log is now: [Sat Jul 04 17:44:27 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] sh: zip: command not found
```

.

```
[root@server ~]# yum install zip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * extras: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirror.cogentco.com
Setting up Install Process
Package zip-3.0-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

.

```
[root@server ~]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
ionCube Loader
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

.

```
[root@server ~]# php -v
PHP 5.4.27 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2015 18:06:21) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.11, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
```

MORE INFO

I want to add /usr/bin/zip to the executable path for the web server.

I've tried:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/zip
```

AND

cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/zip zip

But neither one worked.

Comment: Can you show us what *which zip* produces

Comment: Result: /usr/bin/zip

Comment: See what happens if you do /usr/bin/zip instead of just zip

Comment: Ok. I changed "zip" to "/usr/bin/zip" in phpinfo.php and the out come was: string(42) "updating: domains/-----.co/ (stored 0%)"

Comment: What are you trying to zip?

Comment: @Cazzette So specifying the full path solved the problem then?

Comment: Yes I believe it did.  Now, how do I do change this in the VPS so that path is always defined and able to be called by any script without having to manually define the full path? Please see my updated post for more details/outcome. @kasperd

Comment: @MichaelBailey I use this method to backup and deploy my websites.

Comment: @Cazzette would it solve this if you stored /usr/bin/zip as a PHP variable $zip? This would work if you have a PHP include on like every script you're calling. Common in a few situation, like db authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Just so I can make it an actual answer so this can be marked solved:

After running **which zip** and locating zip, */usr/bin/zip* triggered successfully while **zip** did not.

As for the new part:
I'd personally store it as a PHP variable (like $zip = /usr/bin/zip) and call it if that solves it. There may be a better solution.

Comment: Hi @Michael Bailey. It's not my software to modify, it's obfuscated. So I cannot edit it's own files like that unfortunately.

Comment: can you clarify this php variable? I'd like it web server wide, so somewhere within php.ini I assume. What would this line look like? I don't want to screw this up.

Comment: I just mean a lot of PHP web apps have a header.php that they include in all their pages. Kinda a non-answer.